# Bootstrap 4 Flexbox Horizontal Scrolling Cards NOT working with less then 8 cards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Having an issue with Bootstrap 4 flexbox in creating horizontally scrollable cards on Desktop Screens ( works okay on mobile responsive mode):

Issue # 1:  Unless there are a minimum of 8 cards, the cards are not filling the horizontal flexbox 'visible' window properly

Case A: 3 cards, the flexbox window is totally skewed and the 'badge' from below bills in there.

 Case B: 7 cards,  flexbox is almost filled, but there is a gap on left side. 
 Case C: 8 cards, all perfect , visible & scrolling perfectly.

Issue 2: if the content in the card pushes the Button, how can I fill it with space, so that the buttons are in line?

@CBroe  you gave the cue, i added   .row { width:100%; max-width:100vw; }

and now it is working as expected , updating the

[image: Case A, B , C]

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.forlabel {
  margin-top: -14px;
}

.forlabeldiv {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  <!-- margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  -->margin: 0, auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.forlabelspan {
  color: #0275d8;
  background: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.btn {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center margin-bottom:5px
}

.card-block {
  min-height: 20vh;
  min-width: 25vw;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.profile,
.card {
  background: #ced7df!important;
  text-align: center;
}

.master {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0, auto;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.badge {
  width: 10rem;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Single Row Horizontal Scrolling Cards</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>

<body>
  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->
  <h2>Case A: Horizontal Scrolling Cards with 3 cards</h2>
  <div class="container-fluid p-3 m-3 master">
    <div class="container forlabeldiv row  max-auto">
      <label for="input1" class="col-sm-12 forlabel">
       <span class=" forlabelspan">Expert Panel</span> 
    </label>

      <div class="row flex-nowrap overflow-auto ">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff.png" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> 1 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>2 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>3 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>
      <!--*** end of row flex  *** -->

      <div class="badge badge-secondary text-wrap text-center">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i> Swipe for More <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--*** end of label div  *** -->
  </div>
  <!--*** end of container-flex -->

  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->



  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->
  <h2>Case B: Horizontal Scrolling Cards with 7 cards </h2>
  <div class="container-fluid p-3 m-3 master">
    <div class="container forlabeldiv row  max-auto">
      <label for="input1" class="col-sm-12 forlabel">
       <span class=" forlabelspan">Expert Panel</span> 
    </label>

      <div class="row flex-nowrap overflow-auto">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff.png" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> 1 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>2 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>3 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>4 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>5 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>6 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>7 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--*** end of row flex  *** -->
      <div class="badge badge-secondary text-wrap text-center">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i> Swipe for More <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--*** end of label div  *** -->
  </div>
  <!--*** end of container-flex -->

  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->

  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->
  <h2> Case C: Horizontal Scrolling Cards with 8 cards</h2>
  <div class="container-fluid p-3 m-3 master">
    <div class="container forlabeldiv row  max-auto">
      <label for="input1" class="col-sm-12 forlabel">
       <span class=" forlabelspan">Expert Panel</span> 
    </label>

      <div class="row flex-nowrap overflow-auto">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff.png" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br> 1 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>2 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br> First Name Last Name<br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>3 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>4 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>5 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>6 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>7 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-3">
          <div class="card card-block profile h-100 d-flex flex-auto">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"> First Name Last Name<br>8 <br> Title of Person<br> Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto mt-auto">BOOK</a>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
      <!--*** end of row flex  *** -->
      <div class="badge badge-secondary text-wrap text-center">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i> Swipe for More <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--*** end of label div  *** -->
  </div>
  <!--*** end of container-flex -->

  <!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->


</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why should _three_ cards that are _three_ columns wide each, behave any differently, inside a row that is made to display _12_ columns?

Comment: In actual case the content is  pulled from a database, so can have 0 or more cards ( based on number of records for the selection). I there a different way to deal with this?

Comment: The main problem is that the width of the row in your first examples collapses - because you are using `.row`, which is by default a flex container to get elements _next_ to each other, to get them _below_ each other. Only that doesn't work if the row has so little content, that the next element still fits next to it. Add `flex-direction: column;` to those rows.

Comment: @CBroe i added  .row { flex-direction: column' } to the style sheet but didn't work. All cards goes into  one column vertical. what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cues from experts here, resolved the issues:

1. Added  .row { width:100%; max-width:100vw; } to ensure even with 3 cards the width of the flex-box doesn't shrink.
2. Added d-flex flex-auto to card & mt-auto to ensure buttons appear in same line

Thank you